# Set corner radius of `UISegmentedControl` equal to that of `UISearchController`

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, uisearchcontroller

I have several boxes on a page and I would like them all the have the corner radius of the `UISearchController` also on that page.

I tried to set the corner radius of my segmented control equal to that of the search controller. However, `_searchController.searchBar.layer.cornerRadius` returns `0` instead of its actual value in both `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear`.

I tried the textfield inside of the search bar, but it also returns `0` for its corner radius.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define CornerRadius    6

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

    [self.userNameTextfield.layer setCornerRadius:CornerRadius];
    [self.userNameTextfield.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_login"]].CGColor];
    [self.userNameTextfield.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
    [self.userNameTextfield.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

    [self.passwordTextfield.layer setCornerRadius:CornerRadius];
    [self.passwordTextfield.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_login"]].CGColor];
    [self.passwordTextfield.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
    [self.passwordTextfield.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

set both corner radius like this